# Need help with leaf equation

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am looking for a leaf equation that I can plot on a polar coordination graph. I have been using this as reference but is there something more efficient?

https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VirtualFlowersWithCrispatePetals/

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? The demonstration shows some quite intricate three-dimensional shapes using just three equations with a total of nine parameters. Do you want something **simpler**, such as a mere two-dimensional outline of some kind of "leaf" shape?

Comment: Yes, something simple for me to grasp so I can build on top of. I was able to understand the petal with trial and error. I tried tweaking the equations but it seemed off.